# API URL Design - query or path parameters

Tags: url, api-design

We have a model where Object A is one-to-many with Object B.

We have an API where we want to get object A by it's Id so we have the URL /objectA/:id. That's fine and seems pretty standard.
We also need an endpoint where we can get Object A from object B's Id. (The parent of object B)

What would be the best solution for the URL for this? Should we be using path parameters or query parameters?

/objectA?objectBId=:id

/objectA/fromObjectBId/:id

something else?

Answer (score 1):

First, I'd encourage you to think of your URIs as the IDs and not have the client try to construct URIs from IDs.

That said, since your talking about *relationship*, I'd tend to indicate that from the side of the relationship that's known. So instead of trying to model everything in terms of 'getting' `ObjectA` by using that URL root, instead traverse to it *from* `ObjectB`.

So the path might look something like:

`/ObjectB/1234/ObjectA`